# py2neo and Neo4j for Windows desktop can't connect

Tags: python, database, neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo

I always get this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    graph.create(alice_knows_bob)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py", line 355, in create
    with self.begin() as tx:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py", line 346, in begin
    return Transaction(self, autocommit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py", line 758, in __init__
    self.transaction = self.connector.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo\internal\connectors.py", line 290, in begin
    tx = self.pool.acquire()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py", line 704, in acquire
    return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py", line 597, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2neo\internal\connectors.py", line 225, in connector
    return connect(address_, auth=cx_data["auth"], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py", line 960, in connect
    raise last_error
neobolt.exceptions.AuthError: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
```

I try to connect like this:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()

remote_graph = Graph("bolt://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7687/db/data/")
```

I am not sure where to find my real user name and password. Or do I do auth wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

First, make sure to open `http://localhost:7474/browser/` and input username `neo4j` and the password you set when creating the graph. If you can log in, then you have the right username and password.

Next, make sure you install py2neo version 2.0.8. The newer version somehow has a problem with authentication.

Then use this code to authenticate:

```
from py2neo import Graph, authenticate
graph = Graph()
# Authenticate the user using py2neo.authentication

authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "<pass>")

# # Connect to Graph and get the instance of Graph

remote_graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```